# Can't Start Kafka Server on Windows 10 - Kafka's log directories (and children) should only contain Kafka topic data

Tags: apache-kafka, windows-10

Following instructions in [lesson 28 of Learn Apache Kafka for Beginners Udemy course](https://www.udemy.com/course/apache-kafka/learn/lecture/11566904#overview) to start zookeeper and then start a kafka server broker on Windows 10. Zookeeper runs fine on port 2181:

```
C:\kafka_2.12-2.3.1> zookeeper-server-start.bat config/zookeeper.properties
```

> ...
>
> INFO binding to port 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181

But after adding the bat files to path, running kafka server does not work:

```
C:\kafka_2.12-2.3.1> kafka-server-start.bat config/server.properties
```

> ...
>
> ERROR There was an error in one of the threads during logs loading: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Found directory C:\kafka_2.12-2.3.1\data\kafka, 'kafka' is not in the form of topic-partition or topic-partition.uniqueId-delete (if marked for deletion).
>   Kafka's log directories (and children) should only contain Kafka topic data. (kafka.log.LogManager)

Some of the stdout logging in zookeeper looks informative:

> Accepted socket connection from /127.0.0.1:49439 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory)
>   [2019-11-03 17:22:42,278] INFO Client attempting to establish new session at /127.0.0.1:49439 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
>   [2019-11-03 17:22:42,286] INFO Creating new log file: log.1 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.FileTxnLog)
>
> ...
>
> INFO Processed session termination for sessionid: 0x1007b0044a40000 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor)
>   [2019-11-03 17:22:42,987] INFO Closed socket connection for client /127.0.0.1:49439 which had sessionid 0x1007b0044a40000 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn)

Under the `data` folder I created, there are two folders I created, the second of which was filled after I tried running the kafka broker:

`kafka/`
  |-- empty
`zookeeper/`
  |-- `version-2/`
      |--`log.1`

Why does this error happen and how can I start a Kafka server on Windows 10?

EDIT:

Contents of `config/server.properties`:

> num.network.threads=3
>
> num.io.threads=8
>
> socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400
>
> socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400
>
> socket.request.max.bytes=104857600
>
> log.dirs=C:/kafka_2.12-2.3.1/data/
>
> num.partitions=1
>
> num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1
>
> offsets.topic.replication.factor=1
>
> transaction.state.log.replication.factor=1
>
> transaction.state.log.min.isr=1
>
> log.retention.hours=168
>
> log.segment.bytes=1073741824
>
> log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000
>
> zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181
>
> zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000
>
> group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=0

Comment: Could you please post the content of `config/server.properties` (comments can be excluded) ?

Comment: Sorry, could you also please show the directory names and filenames under C:\kafka_2.12-2.3.1\data\kafka ?

Comment: @iamabug I edited the question with the file contents and server.properties.

Comment: I think @cricket_007 is right. The error message says `Kafka's log directories (and children) should only contain Kafka topic data`. Removing zookeeper directory should be the solution.

Answer (score 0):

> The data/ folder contains empty zookeeper/ and kafka/ directories

Did you create those folders? Kafka's `log.dirs` can only contain folders in the format of `topic-partition or topic-partition.uniqueId-delete (if marked for deletion)`, as mentioned by the error. That folder should be empty (no subdriectories) if starting fresh installation.

Plus, Kafka data directory should not hold Zookeeper data as Zookeeper should be independent of Kafka

Comment: I created that folder, yes, and used the path in `log.dirs` in properties files. Just following the steps described in the Udemy course. I think they're meant to hold logs. Should Zookeeper logs be kept outside this `kafka_2.12-2.3.1` directory?

Comment: I cannot login to Udemy to see what it suggests, but Kafka creates the folder automatically, so you don't need to. And yes, Zookeeper data should be separate from Kafka. In production environments, they are even on separate machines.